# 400 error when using custom query in elasticsearch on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I cant figure out how to run search query with filter on nested object and with sort. I keep getting

```
[400] {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;
```

My searchable concern looks like this:

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    def self.search(query="", options={})

       params = {
          query: {
            filtered: {
              query: {
                multi_match: {
                  query: query,
                  fields: ['title', 'description', 'product_url']
                },
                match_all: {}
              },
              filter: {
                bool: {
                  must: [
                    {
                      terms: {
                        gender: options[:gender]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      nested: {
                        path: 'prices',
                        filter: {
                          bool: {
                            must: [
                              {
                                term: { 'prices.currency' => options[:p_curr] }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          sort: [
            {
              options[:order_col].try(:downcase) => {
                order: 'desc'
              }
            }
          ]
        }

        params[:query][:filtered][:query].delete(:match_all) if query.present?
        params[:query][:filtered][:query].delete(:multi_match) if query.blank?
        params.delete(:sort) if options[:order_col].blank?

        __elasticsearch__.search(params).page(options[:page]).per(options[:per_page])
      end

    # elastic search index
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def as_indexed_json(options={})
      as_json(
        :only => [:title, :description, :product_url, :gender],
        :include => [
          :brand => {
            :only => [:name, :slug]
          }, 
          :retailer => {
            :only => [:name]
          }, 
          :product_text_tags => {
            :only => [:name]
          },
          :prices => {
            :only => [
              :price_in_cents,
              :currency,
              :is_on_sale,
              :out_of_stock,
              :on_sale_price_in_cents,
              :is_last_price
            ]
          }
        ]
      )
    end
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  end

end
```

Am I missing something? can anyone please help here. I feel pretty lost. Everything works fine with elastic, when I remove all the conditions and filters it works fine when I just use normal query
Working on Rails 3

Comment: There should be more info in the elasticsearch logs.  what is the  actual query that is being submitted?

Comment: where can i found the logs?

Comment: If you don't daemonize it, elasticsearch will print that stuff out to the console, if not then in the logs folder by default